# Xcode 4 NSRangeException Error after split string

Tags: xcode, indexoutofboundsexception, nsrangeexception

I'm trying to split a string and separate it into variable but am getting the following error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 2 beyond bounds [0 ..
>   1]'

Code:

```
NSLog(@"%@", strResult);

    NSArray* LocInfo = [strResult componentsSeparatedByString: @"|"];
    NSString* Response1 = [LocInfo objectAtIndex: 0];
    NSString* Response2 = [LocInfo objectAtIndex: 1];
    NSString* Response3 = [LocInfo objectAtIndex: 2];
```

Any ideas?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `strResult` is broken into `LocInfo` array that contains only two elements, and you tried to access third one.

As your string already contains 1 / 2 or 3 `NSString`s, therefore no need to again store then into `NSString`, you can directly use them by `LocInfo[index]`.

If you need to check how many strings are there simply use : `[LocInfo count];`

Comment: Yeah I had a string that was being returned from a web-service and sometimes it wasn't passing back the 3rd element.  Thanks!

Comment: so no need to hardcode to index:3, check if its count is 3 only then access that element.

Comment: Will do!  And I'll accept your response as the answer here once it allows me to.